# Firebase Queue - Handling Reject/Resolve while Looping

Tags: firebase

I have a Queue that looks like this

```
new Queue(queueRef, options, ({post, user, postId}, progress, resolve, reject) => {
  rootRef.child(`users/${user.user_id}/followers`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    const followers = toArray(snapshot.val())
    for (var i = 0; i < followers.length; i++) {
      rootRef.child(`users/${followers[i].user_id}/feed/${postId}`).set(post, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else if (i >= followers.length - 1) {
          resolve({post, user, postId})
        }
      })
    }
  }, reject)
})
```

My issue is that I'm really only resolving once all the `set`s have finished and rejecting if any of those fail. What I'd like to do is somehow pass each iteration of a loop to another Queue which can then `reject/resolve` for that specific request rather than the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and probably has a better solution. But you're looking for something like [Q.all()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

In essence, call a method that does each op and returns a promise, and resolve/reject when the entire set is done.

```
new Queue(queueRef, options, ({post, user, postId}, progress, resolve, reject) => {
  rootRef.child(`users/${user.user_id}/followers`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    var promiseList = [], p;
    const followers = toArray(snapshot.val())
    for (var i = 0; i < followers.length; i++) {
       p = processNextFollower(followers[i]);
       // p.then(progress);
       promiseList.push(p); 
    }
    Q.all(promiseList).then(resolve, reject);
  }, reject)
})

function processNextFollower(follower, postId) {
   var def = Q.defer();
   rootRef.child(`users/${follower.user_id}/feed/${postId}`).set(post, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          def.reject(err)
        } else if (i >= followers.length - 1) {
          def.resolve({post, user, postId})
        }
      })
    }
   return def.promise;
}
```